# Error while inserting data to database values does not match table defination

Tags: sql, .net

I am trying to insert data to database through visual basic .net table definition error occurred

[image]

Comment: welcome to stack overflow.  first, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to format a question post correctly.

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteReader is the wrong commmand

try [ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)